# WPF: Databinding to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

This is my first post in this forum, though I am a long-time lurker. I have started learning WPF for about a couple of months now, and I am trying to create an application just for training purposes.

I have a backend database which I have added to my application using EF6 ORM. In my application, I have a `ComboBox which needs to be populated by a column in a table of the database. That I can do using binding to a list.

The part I am having trouble with is the `DataGrid`. The columns of the `DataGrid` needs to be populated according to the `Item` chosen in the `ComboBox`.

My database:

[image: Here is my database structure]

As you can see, the school has several departments, and each of those department has a HOD and a student strength.

My application:

[image: Here is the snapshot of the app]

The `ComboBox` will be populated with school names. The `DataGrid` will be populated once the schoolname is selected. The `DataGrid` will have each row for each department available for the school. So I need to bind the corresponding columns with the departments of the corresponding schools. That much I get. However, then I want to save the user-entered comments in the Feedback `TextBox`.

I cannot understand how to create a class so that I can bind the `DataGrid` to the object of it. Is it possible to bind the `DataGrid` to an object and then bind the columns separately to another object?

**EDIT**

Apart from the entities created from the database, I have two classes:

```
class Feedback : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _school;

    public string School
    {
        get
        {
            return _school;
        }

        set
        {
            _school = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("School");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<FeedbackLine> _feedbackLines;

    public ObservableCollection<FeedbackLine> FeedbackLines
    {
        get
        {
            return _feedbackLines;
        }

        set
        {
            _feedbackLines = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FeedbackLines");
        }
    }

    public Feedback(string school)
    {
       //Insert some Linq Query to populate the FeedbackLines
       //something like
       //var FeedbackLines = Context.Schools.Where(c => c.SchoolName == school)
       //                                   .Select(c => new {Department = c.AvailableDepts.Dept, etc etc}.ToList();
       //but then what?
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
    }
}
```

This is supposed to be bound to the datagrid. And the FeedbackLine is:

```
public class FeedbackLine: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _dept;

    public string Department
    {
        get { return _dept; }
        set { _dept = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Department");
        }
    }

    private string _HOD;

    public string HOD
    {
        get { return _HOD; }
        set { _HOD = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HOD");
        }
    }

    private int _strength;

    public int Strength
    {
        get { return _strength; }
        set { _strength = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Strength");
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }

    private string _comment;

    public string Comment
    {
        get { return _comment; }
        set { _comment = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Comment");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I haven't had much headway with the ViewModel. Problem is, I am not very good with LINQ. And there are too many classes and objects and I have no idea which one to bind with which. The only vague idea that I can get is that I have to use LINQ to query the database using the selected `School`, and then populate the `FeedbackLines` using that.

**Edit 2:**
For anyone who's interested, here's my model diagram in WPF:
[Model Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJw2p.png)

**Edit 3:**
I think I am confused about ViewModel. The data that will be displayed on the screen is not necessarily the data to be saved. For example, I don't want to save the unselected rows. My `Feedback` class tries to display the data as well as save it. And therein lies the problem. Can't a `DataGrid` be bound to an object, while its columns be bound to other objects? For example, if I choose to use a `Combobox` for Department. Then I need to use `ItemsSource` for displaying items, but need to save the `SelectedItem` only. I can't find a way to separate these two concerns.

Comment: is it possible to share the code?

Comment: post your code.

Comment: By code, do you mean the viewmodel or the xaml?

Comment: I suggest following a tutorial for MvvmLight: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1037/mvvm-light-wpf-model-view-viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your Feedback constructor

```
public Feedback(string school, List<FeedbackLine> feedbackLines)
{
    School = school;
    FeedbackLines = new ObservableColleytion<FeedbackLine>(feedbackLines);
}
```

It's a better architecture if your data viewmodel does not have a connection to the database. You can put your select in a seperate class.

If you need help with your LINQ statement I can help you.

In your Feedback constructor you wrote

```
//but then what?
```

When you got your data you can create instances of FeedbackLines to add them in the new constructor I showed above.

When you did this your viewmodel (which is DataContext of your view) needs an

```
public void ObservableCollection<Feedback> Feedbacks
```

with INotifyPropertyChanged like you did it in the other viewmodels.

In your xaml you have your ComboBox with the schools. Give that combobox a name, e.g. SchoolsComboBox.
In your DataGrid write this line

```
Source={Binding ElementName=SchoolsComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.FeedbackLines}
```

/edit for adding LINQ 
You created an anonymous type. Just create a FeedbackLine instead and you're fine.

```
var feedbackLines = Context.Schools.Where(c => c.SchoolName == school)
                                    .Select(c => new FeedbackLine
                                            {
                                                Department = c.AvailableDepts.Dept, 
                                                HOD = c.AvailableDepts.HeadOfDept, 
                                                Strength = c.AvailableDepts.StudentStrength}
                                    .ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It made the architecture much cleaner. As for the LINQ, I'm still stuck. I'm using something like `var FeedbackLines = Context.Schools.Where(c => c.SchoolName == school).Select(c => new {Department = c.AvailableDepts.Dept, HOD = c.AvailableDepts.HeadOfDept, Strength = c.AvailableDepts.StudentStrength}.ToList()` but this returns an IEnumerable of anonymous objects. How should I cast this to FeedbackLines?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added the LINQ statement. If it's working I would be happy when you upvote and accept my answer :)

Comment: Did the upvote, but my reputation doesnt allow it to be made public. Sorry. Thanks for the LINQ. It works, at least the cursory check showed that.

Comment: There is one more help that I need. Where should I plug in the LINQ statement? Is there a better place to  call it from than the setter of the SelectedSchool (the SelectedItem of Combobox)?

Answer (score 0):

U can make Something like this. Im sure it can be writen better but it works.

In your ViewModel make 3 Properties that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

One for your collection that will you bind to your ComboBox(make it ObservableCollection), One for SelectedItem from your ComboBox( you bind it to SelectedItem in comboBox) and another ObservableCollection that you will Bind to DataGrid)

For example you have in XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="200"
              Margin="20"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOne}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right "
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="300"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    </DataGrid>
```

and in your ViewModel you can have something like this.

```
     public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
            {
                get { return _products; }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _products)
                    {
                        _products = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            private ObservableCollection<Product> _selectedOne;
            public ObservableCollection<Product> SelectedOne
            {
                get { return _selectedOne; }
                set { 
                       _selectedOne = value; 
                       OnPropertyChanged();
                     }
            }

            public int SelectedProductId
            {
                get { return _selectedProductId; }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _selectedProductId)
                    {
                        _selectedProductId = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            public Product SelectedProduct
            {
                get { return _selectedProduct; }
                set
                {
                    if (value ! = _selectedProduct) 

                {
                    _selectedProduct = value;

                    // clear your list of selected objects and then add just selected one
                    // or you dont clear it, and items will be added in DataGrid when selected in ComboBox
                    SelectedOne.Clear();
                    SelectedOne.Add(_selectedProduct);

                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
```

Code to Populate Products, DataGrid will be populated by selecting Item from ComboBox.

u can go in ViewModel constructor and make something like this.

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
            {
                using (YourDbContext context = new YourDbContext ())
                {
                    var productList = new ObservableCollection<Product>(context.Products);
                    productList.ToList()
                    Products = productsList;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the code to populate the datagrid or the combobox?

Comment: I've added sample in ViewModel how you can populate your list od Items. Your DataGrid will be populatet by selecting Item from ComboBox, thats why we have make SelectedOne property as Collection, and if u want to add more(like stack) in DataGrid you can, or you can just Add one by previously clearing that collection, sample made in SelectedProduct Set property.